# Webpage loading blank

Tags: apache-2.2, php

My website http://www.markupchop.com not rendering the PHP file in server. Even HTML file also loading blank. But the files like .txt .xml are running properly.

For example : http://www.markupchop.com/sitemap.xml

The website is developed using PHP. Even index.php not running. FTP working well.

### Server details are below :

Apache Version: Apache/2.2.17
PHP Version:    5.3

Till day before yesterday website loaded perfectly, but yesterday onwards am getting only blank page.

Please help me what's wrong with this.

Comment: More info needed - what exactly happens? It gives the php back as if it were html?

Comment: Check your logs. There may be an error in your php.